# How i can delete last block from blockchain? altcoin

Tags: blockchain, blockchain-fork, altcoin-development, daemon, getblocktemplate

How can I delete the last block from blockchain to be ready for hardfork.
What I mean is, in blockchain last block is with error's. I want to delete those blocks, for the new blockchain is disabled from the last block.

- How can I mine new block if last block would be 1 day old? How do I understand that the daemon does not start giving work to pool/miner, if last block is very old? They will be trying to find new block's from peer, even if it does not exist ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't delete a block, just mine a new block on top of the previous block, creating a fork. Just reference the parent block as the parent of your new block, and if you mine more on top of your new chain, it will become the accepted chain.
The age of the block shouldn't matter.

Comment: where i can read about it with more detail's, i little not understand how i can reference if it's need to bee based on previous block( mined ). About age block.
before daemon start say ( 100% searchen for new block's on network , getblocktemplate start after by sync...)

Comment: i to think its shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

First sync up your client with the latest blocks. And then you can continue from there. But blocks are irreversible. That's how the blockchain is designed.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin